# Best way to secure a cat enclosure to the ground?

Tags: fastener, pet-proofing

I'd like to make a small outdoor cat enclosure for my cat.  I shouldn't have any problems securing it on the tops and sides but i'm curious if anyone has suggestions for securing it to the ground?  The bottom will be touching dirt and I want to make sure that my cat cannot get out AND that no critters can get in.  Suggestions?

Comment: Dig the side walls into the ground like 1 metre deep so it cant dig under it like Karl said. Animals, are well.. animals.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, agree with "ppumkin" above suggestion of burying the side walls into the ground. In North America 2ft (600mm) is deep enough to keep any critters out, though I am saying that from a gardening prospective, so going down even deeper might not be a bad idea...

Comment: Especially since cats are some sort of liquid apparently. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wp4ZD0lMtAY&feature=related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats are just as capable of digging as dogs are. Dogs are capable of digging to get to a trapped and tasty treat.

The best thing I can recommend, after years of work to contain psychotic dogs when they're outside, is to have a full enclosure -- top, bottom, all four sides.